# Problem in regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I am trying to remove multiple spaces by using below codes,its removing &nbsp also,
but its not working for character  N B S P.....

```
replace(SPACE, " ").replace(/^[\s\t\n\&nbsp\;]+|[\s\t\n\&nbsp\;]+$/g, '');
```

Comment: Please, give an example of a string you want to get before and after replace. A few examples. Just can't understand how this must work.

Comment: It's 'not' working for N B S P? Are you stripping spaces or trying to remove these characters too? Or do you mean it is not stripping out a capitalised &NBSP;?

Comment: I think he means that &nbsp; is interpreted as __& or n or b or s or p or ;__ which is confusing, and not what you want is you try to remove HTML whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
str.replace(/(&nbsp;)|[ \t\n]/g, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be less complex imho:

```
(' replace &nbsp;-s and spaces &NBSP; in this line&nbsp; ok? ')
      .replace(/&nbsp;|\s|\s+/gi, '');
//=>result: 'replace-sandspacesinthislineok?'
```

With this RegExp/replace all instances of spaces/&nbsp;-s are replaced with an empty string.

```
/&nbsp;|\s|\s+/gi
-------^ or operator, so: match &nbsp; OR \s OR \s+
---------------^g modifier: match all instances in the string to search
-----------------^i modifier: match case insensitive
```

An even shorter form would be:

```
    /(&nbsp;|\s)+/gi
----------------^ + match the preceding element one or more times
```

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is your friend

Answer (score 1):

Try `/([ \r\n\t]|&nbsp;)/g` to remove all whitespace in the string,
Try `/^([ \r\n\t]|&nbsp;)/g` to remove all whitespace from the beginning of the string,
Try `/([ \r\n\t]|&nbsp;)$/g` to remove all whitespace from the end of the string,

Answer (score 1):

To replace leading and trailing white-space and `&nbsp;` you can do:

```
str.replace(/^(&nbsp;|\s)+|(&nbsp;|\s)+$/gi, '')
```

The reason by `n` `b` `s` `p` and `;` are being deleted from your string is because of the incorrect character class:

```
[\s\t\n\&nbsp\;]
```

which also matches characters `n` `b` `s` `p` and `;`.

Also note that `\s` includes `\t` and `\n`.

In case if you want to delete all whitespace characters and all `&nbsp;` from the string you can do:

```
str.replace(/(&nbsp;|\s)+/gi, '')
```